# How to create structure in MATLAB with many repeated substructures in an efficient way?

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I need to create a structure in MATLAB which is like this: under the main struct there are 3 sub-structures: Left, Right, Center. Under Left and Right there are 18 sub-structures each (A,B,C,D,E,...), and under Center there are 5 sub-structures.
Under each of the 18 and 5 sub-structures I have 3 numerical vectors: x, y, z (representing cartesian coordinates). 
My question is, how to create this big structure without a clumsy and very long command in which I should repeat the same field names over and over? and without using loops? is there any command, like "deal" I can use and how?

Thank ahead!

Comment: All values set to zero or is there data which should be used?

Comment: there is data to use

Comment: Please give an example for the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea to create the `Left` field. You could try to adapt it to create the other fields as well:

```
myStruct.Left = cell2struct(repmat({repmat(struct('x', [], 'y', [], 'z', []), 3, 1)}, 18, 1), num2cell('A':'R'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use class,
class is generally a structure but could have methods,etc.

for example you can have vector class:

```
classdef Myvector
    properties
            x;
            y;
            z;
    end
    methods 
            function obj=Myvector(obj,xin,yin,zin)
                  obj.x=xin;
                  obj.y=yin;
                  obj.z=zin;
            end
    end
 end
```

so you could use this as following:

```
 B=struct('A',Myvector(1,2,3),...
```

even you could define other classes to abstract your code.

even you can use

```
 cell2struct
```

function in matlab (follow matlab doc for more info)